# sql 2 table query problem

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables in a database. I use following query:

```
Select U.id, U.ad, COUNT(B.id) AS 'total' 
FROM tblProducts U 
  INNER JOIN TblBasvurular B ON B.urunid=U.id 
GROUP BY u.id,u.ad
```

this show me

```
id   | productname   |  total
-------------------------------
1    | bread         | 2
2    | water         | 3
3    | milk          | 1
```

but I can't see other products. If does not exist it does not show me others.

How can I get result like this:

```
id | productname | total
-------------------------------
1  | egg         | 0
2  | bread       | 2
3  | water       | 3
4  | tea         | 0
5  | milk        | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear enough, because you didn't show us second table.
But try to change inner join to left join in your query:

```
select 
U.id,
U.ad,
COUNT(B.id) as 'total' 
from tblProducts U 
left join TblBasvurular B on B.urunid=U.id 
Group by u.id,u.ad
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify your RDBMS, but assuming it is SQL Server:

```
select U.id, U.ad, COUNT(ISNULL(B.id, 0)) as 'total' 
from tblProducts U 
left join TblBasvurular B on B.urunid = U.id 
Group by u.id, u.ad
```

Comment: How do you know it is Microsft database? Does ISNULL() work for Oracle or MySQL as well?

Comment: Aren't all databases SQL server? ;)  It was an assumption on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN:

```
select U.id,U.ad,COUNT(B.id)as 'total' 
from tblProducts U LEFT join TblBasvurular B on B.urunid=U.id 
Group by u.id,u.ad
```

If it is Oracle, then try this:

```
select U.id,U.ad,NVL(COUNT(B.id),0) as 'total' 
from tblProducts U LEFT join TblBasvurular B on B.urunid=U.id 
Group by u.id,u.ad
```

This will display 0 instead of NULL.

If it is SQL Server, use ISNULL instead of NVL; if it is MySQL, use IFNULL.

For all of these RDBMSs, the function `coalesce` works.